# Error in jQuery with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, jquery

I am using jquery Ajax following line of code having problem only with **Firefox** and **Blackbarry** browsers

**postion:**

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(currentPosition);

function currentPosition(res){
                window.res = res;
}
```

**Code:**

```
var postion = window.res;

    $.ajax({
          url: 'SendLocation',
          type: 'post', 
          data: position, // Position is navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
          success: function(res){
                alert(res);
       }
    });
```

**Error:**

```
NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO: Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object

value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : ( value == null ? "" : value );
```

After reading [FormData Object not submitting via jQuery AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809016/formdata-object-not-submitting-via-jquery-ajax-call) post I added following line of code and code become 
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,

**Updated code:**

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'SendLocation',
      type: 'post', 
      data: position, // Position is navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
      processData: false,   //Added this line
      contentType: false,   //Added this line

      success: function(res){
            alert(res);
   }
});
```

with this no error was oucurring but code also stops working.

Comment: do you mean, `position = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`? because that would be invalid. `position = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(...)` would also be invalid.

Comment: And you know how to geolocate, and that it's async ?

Comment: @adeneo I am using gerolocation async.

Comment: @KevinB I have updated the question for your understanding but this is just an example.

Comment: You'll need to place the ajax call inside the geolocation callback function, `currentPosition`, otherwise you don't have anyting to send, yet !

Comment: @adeneo I am getting position. There is no problem with that. The position object is not empty. This type of error is ouccring because of type of the data present in position object which is against the security of Firefox that is why its saying "Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object"

Comment: What's happening is jQuery is trying to convert the object to a string. You need to instead convert said object to the string that your server-side system is expecting so that jQuery won't attempt to do it for you. you can't send a javascript object as-is over ajax, it has to be converted to a string format. jQuery can handle that conversion for you with simple objects, but with more complex objects, it can't.

Comment: @KevinB then how its working for Chrome and IE10 ?

Comment: They just so happen to allow jquery to process it? it doesn't matter. If you properly convert it to a string, it won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all guess for helping me out but here let me tell you what I did.
I just just select my required values from the **position** object and create a new object and filled it with my data that I got from **position** and POST it to the server and now its working fine Thanks..!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using serialize() on your position variable as it would be trying to send the geolocation DOM object..

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition

This error would show up if you were using firebug and inspecting your POST vars.

Comment: No can't use serailize becuase I need object on NodeJS server as it is.

Comment: @ArhamAliQureshi You can't send arbitrary javascript objects to the server.  Maybe you should be more specific about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @AaronDufour. I am using NodeJS server, it is a javaScript server understand javaScript Objects. Working fine in Chrome and IE10

Comment: @ArhamAliQureshi Repeating yourself really isn't going to get you anywhere. _What are you actually doing with the object?_ My guess is that the browsers it's working in serialize that object in its `toString` method.